# Check integer number is between two values

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a int variable named `number` with value `21`.

```
int number = 21;

if (number >= 6 && number < 12) {
    System.out.println("catch 1");
}
else if (number >= 12 && number < 17) {
    System.out.println("catch 2");
}
else if (number >= 17 && number < 21) {
    System.out.println("catch 3");
}
else if (number >= 21 && number < 6) {
    System.out.println("catch 4");
}
```

Why i can't see the `catch 4` message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly doubt that a number will, at the same time, be greater than 21 and less than 6. You probably mean `26` instead of `6`.

Comment: Considering the progression, the OP probably meant 24. (12 - 6 = 6, 17 - 12 = 5, 21 - 17 = 4, x - 21 = 3 => x = 24)

Answer (score 2):

Because the value `21` is not less than `6`

So when the line `else if (number >= 21 && number < 6) {` is evaluated, the program sees:

```
else if (21 >= 21 && 21 < 6) {
```

which becomes:

```
else if (true && false) {
```

which becomes

```
else if (false) {
```

If you change this line to say `else if (number >= 21 && number > 6) {` then you will see `catch 4`

NOTE: that would be the same as saying `else if (number > 6) {`

EDIT: based on the the title of your question it seems you are trying to check if `number` is between `6` and `21`

if `number` can equal `6` or `21` that would look like:

```
else if(number <= 21 && number >= 6){
```

if `number` can not equal `6` or `21` that would look like:

```
else if(number < 21 && number > 6){
```